# Array delemiters when writing csv

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a CSV that has a list/array inside using `csv.writer`lib

```
csvwriter.writerow(["1", "2", ["3","4"]])
```

The row that is witen to the file is

```
"1", "2", "[3, 4]"
```

The problem I have with this is that I'm later on trying to upload this CSV to google sheets and the list delimiters `[]` are not the same as google sheets array delimiters `{}`

Is there a way of writing this CSV with the proper array delimiters?

Comment: Would it be a solution to iterate over the elements and when the type of an element is `list`, use `set()` on it, or do the lists contain duplicate values?

Comment: Would not be a solution because 1)  is a big list 2) can have duplicate values

Comment: The solution would be to write code to do that. Note, this isn't really an issue of csv, in csv, by its very nature, **everything is text**. There is no "proper array delimiter" because there is no concept of an array.

Comment: The question was more "Is there a solution using existing libraries"

Answer (score 0):

Format the list into the desired string yourself:

```
def sheet_array(l: list[str]) {
    return f'{{{", ".join(l)}}}'

csvwriter.writerow(["1", "2", sheet_array(["3","4"])]
```